# Tracking Conversion Value on GTM without Data Layer on Ecommerce

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-tag-manager

how are you doing? Hope you're fine.

My name is Thiago. I'm a brazilian enterpreneur that runs a Marketing Agency.

It's been a very long while since I'm in need of help with a very specific matter.

I'll try to explain it here the clearest and easiest as possible.
I'd like to ask sorry for any bad english in advanced. =D

So, the thing is, conversion is a big game changing, whatever it's on Facebook or Google.
Setting up conversions it self isn't that hard, when you have an ecommerce platform that comes with a data layer already setup.

Most of my clients doesn't have an ecommerce with a Data Layer.

I was following the Measure School youtube tutorial to install Active Campaign Tracking, and by doing this I add a template in my Google Tag Manager that almost soved the problem, but the code is note quite working.

And that's where I need help. =D (sorry for the long story kkk)

The Custom Variable "Purchase Function" code is this:

```
 function() {
    var price = str.split("Adicionar R$ ", "{{Click Text}}",[1])
    return price
  }
```

It's returning unedefined.

I'll add some prints showing the whole process with the most details as possible.

[0 - Adding Product to Cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lvrS.png)

[1 - Product Price in Button Click Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXg9r.png)

[2 - Purchase Price Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LrGo.png)

[3 - GTM Price Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV3Q7.png)

I really need help making this Custom Variable "Purchase Price" works.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the split function wrong (for starters, you apply it to a variable `str` which is undefined. Also, wrong number of parameters and wrong parameters).

Look at the documentation for split here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Your function should look something like this:

```
function() {
    // splits Click Text by whitespace an returns an array
    var parts = {{Click Text}}.split(" ");
    // pop removes the last part from the array and returns it 
    // numerical index might not work if there is more than one whitespace in the click text
    price = parts.pop();
    return price;
  }
```